# Passing messages from AuthenticationFailureHandler and LogoutHandler to JSP

Tags: spring, struts2, spring-security

I my application I have created custom AuthenticationFailureHandler and LogoutSuccess handler classes.

Now I want to pass messages from these classes to JSP which should be accessed using struts2 jstl tags.

I dont want to use url parameters for passing messages to jsp page.(login.action?msg=abc)

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to do it, is to put your message to session. In JSP you can access session like that:

```
<s:property value="#session.message"/>
```

Comment: I dont want to use session. I want my application to remain as stateless as possible. Any other ideas